# Mysql Relations related row not updating correctly

Tags: mysql, relational-database

The Problem is occurs When the one of OPID from p_operators is status 1 then
n_notify table all status rows  udating 1
I want it should update only related op_id status...

```
`p_operators` (
  `opID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`opID`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

`n_notify` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `op_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(155) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `op_id` (`op_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

ALTER TABLE `n_notify`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `n_notify_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`op_id`) REFERENCES `p_operators` (`opID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `n_notify_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`status`) REFERENCES `p_operators` (`status`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;


p_operators values
opID    status
5   0
13  1

n_notify values
id  op_id   email   status
2   13  XX  1
3   5   XX  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd constraint links `status` in `p_operators` to `status` in `n_notify`, which ofcourse means, that changing a status in `p_operators` changes **all** equal values of `status` in `n_notify`.

Since you don't want to cascade the status on itself, but the status of a row by id, you do not need a constraint, but a trigger.

Rule of thumb:

- If you need only one field, use a constraint
- If you need two or more fields (id to identify, status to change) use a trigger

Comment: thanks for cooperation Eugen. there are many op_id's. well if you could give an example, appreciate that.